# Uncode theme content block header ignoring saved changes/not updating?

Tags: plugins, themes, visual-editor

I am attempting to change the content block that holds the information for the header on the home page. The content block has successfully been edited by the previous developer but now it seems to ignore all active changes. I have checked to make sure that I"m not mistakenly editing incorrect or unused content. Everything else in the theme seems to save & publish changes as expected. Changes to the content block are still saved and show up correctly on preview but after updating are not displayed on the live site. The theme is Uncode, all other parts of the theme save & reflect changes as expected & the system status in the dashboard is good. Console doesn't show any errors on saving or updating.

Is there a step I'm missing that is specific to content blocks & updating their content? Could this be a plugin causing a conflict and if so what is the best way to determine which plugin is responsible? Is there another approach I can take to debug this issue or otherwise push changes? What else could be causing this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like either a theme bug or conflict with a plugin, hard to say. I would contact the theme developer or check in their support forum.

Comment: I've submitted a help ticket with the theme developer. I'm thinking it may be a plugin conflict.

Comment: You can easily test this theory by disabling all plugins and trying to update the relevant section.

Comment: I created a subdomain & copied the wp install over in order to troubleshoot. I deactivated all plugins then only activated the ones that had the theme's name in it. The content block still won't update. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable even the plugins that have the theme name in it and experiment to see if anything changes.
2. Backup all site and theme data (use backup plugins for site data, most of the time themes have a straightforward way to export theme settings) - perhaps it's the theme settings that got corrupted along the way.
3. It's most likely a bug in the theme itself; you can verify by installing a fresh copy of WP with **only** the theme in question (and its required plugins) and attempting to reproduce the issue.